# Improving runtime of truck pick up and drop off

Tags: python, optimization, runtime

If anyone can help with improving the runtime that would be great!

I have a truck that has a max capacity of C and a beginning stock on it of S1 The truck goes through a fixed route Depot --> 1 --> 2 --> ... --> N-1 --> N --> Depot

Each station i=1…n has a current stock items of Xi and the objective stock items of Xi* At each station the truck can decide to drop-off or take the amount of items possible according to the situation. Let Yi be the number of items left after the truck visited station i The total cost is TC (as written in the code).
I implemented a dynamic programming code whereas xd is the number of units taken or dropped at each station and s is the number of items on the truck: 
run on -min(c-s,xi)<= xd <= s: f(i,s) = f(i+1, s-xd) - so if xd is in minus it means the truck took items from a station.
this is the code - the problem is that it's running for days and not returning an answer.
anyone know a way to implement it better?

```
n = 50
c=10
s1 = 6

xi =  [59,33,14,17,26,31,91,68,3,53,53,73,86,24,98,37,55,14,97,61,57,23,65,24,50,31,39,31,24,60,92,80,48,28,47,81,19,82,3,74,50,89,86,37,98,11,12,94,6,61]
x_star = [35,85,51,88,44,20,79,68,97,7,68,19,50,19,42,45,8,9,61,60,80,4,96,57,100,22,2,51,56,100,6,84,96,69,18,31,86,6,39,6,78,73,14,45,100,43,89,4,76,70]
c_plus = [4.6,1.3,2.7,0.5,2.7,5,2.7,2.6,4.1,4,3.2,3.1,4.8,3.1,0.8,1,0.5,5,5,4.6,2.5,4.1,2.1,2.9,1.4,3.9,0.5,1.7,4.9,0.6,2.8,4.9,3.3,4.7,3.6,2.4,3.4,1.5,1.2,0.5,4.3,4.3,3.9,4.8,1.2,4.8,2,2.2,5,4.5]
c_minus = [8.7,7.5,11.7,6.9,11.7,14.4,7.5,11.1,1.2,1.5,12,8.1,2.7,8.7,9.3,1.5,0.3,1.5,1.2,12.3,5.7,0.6,8.7,8.1,0.6,3.9,0.3,5.4,14.7,0,10.8,6.6,8.4,9.9,14.7,2.7,1.2,10.5,9.3,14.7,11.4,5.4,6,13.2,3.6,7.2,3,4.8,9,8.1]

dict={}
values={}
def tc(i,xd):
    yi = xi[i-1] + xd
    if yi>=x_star[i-1]:
        tc = c_plus[i-1]*(yi-x_star[i-1])
    else:
        tc = c_minus[i-1]*(x_star[i-1]-yi)
    return tc

def func(i,s):
    if i==n+1:
        return 0
    else:

        a=[]
        b=[]
        start = min(c-s,xi[i-1])*-1
        for xd in range(start,s+1):
            cost = tc(i,xd)
            f= func(i+1,s-xd)
            a.append(cost+f)
            b.append(xd)

        min_cost = min(a)
        index = a.index(min_cost)
        xd_optimal = b[index]
        if i in values:
            if values[i]>min_cost:
                dict[i] = xd_optimal
                values[i] = min_cost
        else:
            values[i] = min_cost
            dict[i] = xd_optimal
        return min_cost


best_cost = func(1,s1)
print best_cost
print dict
```

Comment: 1. What is the objective (distribute items evenly, collect them, etc.)? 2. Can the truck run the route several times?

Comment: the objective is minimum cost (cost is calculated as the difference between the "wanted items" in a station (x_star) and the items left after the truck took some or left some items (yi). the truck runs the route only one time and only in the order depot - 1...n - depot.

Comment: c_plus is the cost for having more items than wanted, c_minus is the cost for having less items than wanted.

Comment: Another question, do you happen to run out of memory? Swap thrashing might be an issue.

Comment: No, it ran for 2 days so I stopped it (did this twice). I think the problem is the problem size of 50 stations and the recursion implementation.

Comment: I would definitely get rid of the recursion. Better use a while loop and store everything you need to pass between iterations in a deque.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the solution:
The function is called very often with exactly the same parameters. Thus, I added a cache that avoids repeating the calculations for recurring parameter sets. This returns the answer almost instantly on my computer.

```
cache = {}
def func(i,s):
    if i==n+1:
        return 0
    else:
        try:
            return cache[(i,s)]
        except KeyError:
            pass

        a=[]
        ...
        cache[(i,s)] = min_cost
        return min_cost
```

And here is how I found out what to do...

I modified your code to produce some debug output:

```
...
count = 0

def func(i,s):
    global count
    count += 1
    print count, ':', i, s
...
```

Setting **n** to 2 results in the following output:

```
1 : 1 6
2 : 2 10
3 : 3 10
4 : 3 9
5 : 3 8
6 : 3 7
7 : 3 6
8 : 3 5
9 : 3 4
10 : 3 3
11 : 3 2
12 : 3 1
13 : 3 0
14 : 2 9
15 : 3 10
16 : 3 9
17 : 3 8
18 : 3 7
19 : 3 6
20 : 3 5
21 : 3 4
22 : 3 3
23 : 3 2
24 : 3 1
25 : 3 0
26 : 2 8
27 : 3 10
28 : 3 9
29 : 3 8
30 : 3 7
31 : 3 6
32 : 3 5
...
```

You will notice that the function is called very often with the same set of parameters.
After (i=2, s=10) it runs through all combinations of (i=3, s=x). It does that again after (i=2, s=9). The whole thing finishes after 133 recursions. Setting n=3 takes 1464 recursions, and setting n=4 takes 16105 recursions. You can see where that leads to...

---

Remark: I have *absolutely* no idea how your optimization works. Instead I simply treated the symptoms :)

Comment: amazing i just ran it and it took a second to give the answer, thanks a lot!!

Comment: Hi, can you help us a bit more? we get a solution that is not feasible for example - starting with 6 on the truck - pick up 4 at station 1 (now the truck has 10) then at station 3 unload 10, station 5 - unload 10 - but he doesn't have 10 to unload. do you know what might be the problem?

Comment: I'm afraid I cannot help there. As mentioned in my answer, I don't really know what your algorithm is doing...

Does this happen only with the optimized version or with the original too?